# Is it possible to test other applications like https://www.google.com using capybara in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am new to write test case in Rails. Is it possible to write test cases to test other applications like https://www.google.com using capybara in Rails ?

Answer (score 1):

Capybara uses RackTest by default, which I believe cannot access external urls. However if you change the drive to i.e selenium you should be able to access an external url:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
visit 'https://www.google.com'
```

It can be used to web crawling.